# Time unit used in Apache CXF methods

Tags: java, time, timeout, cxf

In the Apache CXF `HTTPClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout()` and `HTTPClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout()` methods, are the parameters in seconds or milliseconds? It seems trivial, but I can't find the answer anywhere, to begin with the javadoc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I know all web services timeouts is configured in milliseconds, I did not see anywhere that the timeout would be configured in seconds. In your case there is a documentation from `XSD` of:

```
{http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration}HTTPClientPolicy
```

> `ConnectionTimeout:`
>   Specifies the amount of time, in milliseconds, that the consumer will
>   attempt to establish a connection before it times out. 0 is infinite.

This refers [here](http://fusesource.com/docs/framework/2.4/xmlref/http.cxf.apache.org.tr2140572444/types/httpclientpolicy.html#attr_ConnectionTimeout).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally found it. These methods take values in milliseconds. I found the answer here:

http://lhein.blogspot.fr/2008/09/apache-cxf-and-time-outs.html?showComment=1328760737362#c5269809084998987761

Answer (score 1):

The only hint is that it uses a `long` which in Java is usually in milliseconds, but clearly the unit is not documented anywhere.

The method `setConnectionTimeout` should have been named `setConnectionTimeoutMillis` and the JavaDoc should have mentioned this somewhere. Developers should do this whenever a **unit** is involved.

Maybe Java should have had some kind of typed number like `Long<MilliSeconds>` and numbers of the wrong 'unit' would be refused by the compiler :)